# PHP: Any way to make this function more efficient? resourceToOneDimensionalArray (resource to one dimensional array)

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted a function which takes a mysqli_resource (as returned from mysqli_query) and the specific column and returns it as a linear PHP array.  This is what I have now:

```
function resourceToOneDimensionalArray($resource, $field) {
  if($resource == false) return false;
  if(is_array($resource)) {
    if(is_array($resource[0])) {
        $output = array();
        foreach($resource as $row) {
            array_push($output, $row[$field]);
        }
        return $output;
    }
    else {
        return $resource; // already a 1D array, return it
    }
  }
  $array = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resource)) {
    array_push($array, $row[$field]);
  }

  return $array;
}
```

I thought I'd heard about a PHP function that does this, but I can't find it in the docs.  Not sure if I'm just failing at searching, misunderstand the docs themselves, or dreamt up the built-in function.

If this function is as good as it gets, so be it!  Just trying to speed up my code.

Comment: Why should `if(is_array($resource))` be true? Do you handle a variable, which for some reason could be an array **or** a mysqli resource?

Comment: Honestly, I'd have to check the code's 52 instantiations of the function.  Do you suspect that check might slow it down any significant amount?

Comment: No, there's only one little `if` condition per function call, that's no big performance impact. I only wondered why when a resource is expected. You are filtering a single field of a result resource. I guess there's no way to modify the SQL query before fetching the hole table by `mysqli_fetch_all`? And what means "efficient"? Performance or memory consumption?

Comment: No, by the time this function is called the resource is already returned (and passed to it).  It's not possible to modify the query at this point.  I checked and MOST of the queries leading to this call are searching for a single database column, though some function calls ask for multiple (because the local function's returns was based upon passed conditions).  But again, that's outside the scope of this function.

Comment: And can you define "efficient"?

Comment: Ummm.... the best O(n) performance?  I'm pretty sure this is standard definition of "efficient" in programming circles.  Not sure if I understand efficiency more or less than you, but if less I am sincerely open to learning, and if more I am sincerely willing to explain (I've got an extensive tutoring background).  Either way, the enemy is ignorance, never eachother.

Comment: Here are many questions without any computer science background. And complexity theory afaik doesn't catch all use cases in high level programming use cases. People mostly are interested in reducing effective runtime or memory consumption of a specific environment. Often questioners ask ambiguous questions and all answers become useless after the real intention has been clarified. It's not an expert community.

Answer (score 0):

A little performance improvement without effecting the memory consumption could be reached by an index increment, since `array_push` is slower than direct array element access (at least in previous PHP versions, no profiling done in PHP7 yet).

```
$array = array();
$idx = 0
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resource)) {
  $array[$idx++] = $row[$field]);
}
```

You could also profile if there is a significant difference to

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resource)) {
  $array[] = $row[$field]);
}
```

If you don't care about memory consumption, you could fetch the complete table by `mysqli_fetch_all` once and iterate over the rows array picking a single field of it.

Generally you can increase performance in PHP (and many other languages) by avoiding function calls especially within loops, since a non optimized compilation means pushing cpu registers onto the stack and pulling them back after the execution of a subroutine.

There's no native way in `mysqli` to fetch a single column from an already executed query.